# How can i see, if a pipeline script part was re-executed in a retry block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the pipeline script i am using the `retry` block in some cases.

```
retry(1){
  timeout(...){
    try{
      sh 'do something'
    }catch(...){...}
  }
}
```

I could not find any information in the console output, whether a block was "retried". Is there any chance to see if my `retry(1){...}` block works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

retry(1) means the block will only be executed once ( so without any retry )

I tried this:

```
node{
    retry(2){
        float a = 0/0;
    }
}
```

And as you can see, it is shown in de console output:

```
Started by user Carlos Lucas
Running as Carlos Lucas
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/zProves/retry
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] retry
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: Execution failed
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division undefined
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1741)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.BigDecimalMath.divideImpl(BigDecimalMath.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.IntegerMath.divideImpl(IntegerMath.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.NumberMath.divide(NumberMath.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberDiv.invoke(NumberNumberDiv.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
[...]
Retrying
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // retry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division undefined
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1741)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.BigDecimalMath.divideImpl(BigDecimalMath.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.IntegerMath.divideImpl(IntegerMath.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.NumberMath.divide(NumberMath.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberDiv.invoke(NumberNumberDiv.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
[...]
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Thanks! misinterpreted the documentation.